# create XML from DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have two cases here.

1. I am given a DTD and a text file and I need to create an XML file from it.
2. I am given some data that needs to be updated in my XML Document and also a DTD is given.

Since I have multiple documents (~1500 pages/book and there are 8 books), I want to know if I can  automate the above 2 cases. I'm using Altova XML Spy; I also have OxygenXML.

Please let me know how can I achieve the above cases, this would be a great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't well-defined. You need to clearly establish how the text and/or data will be mapped to the XML language defined by the DTD. Once you have done so, you *MAY* be able to construct code which can perform that mapping automatically, if the existing files have sufficiently clear markings to permit those mappings to be made.

But unless it is a well-known DTD and well-known source, it's unlikely that anyone else has already done that work for you or that your source material exactly matches their assumptions.

So the answer is "Yes, some or all of it can probably be automated -- at least well enough for a first pass, to be fixed up in editing -- but you're probably going to have to write the rules at least, and quite possibly the code."